# How to calculate (by hand) the R-squared of a VAR time series model built using R?

Tags: r, time-series, r-squared, vector-autoregression

I have created a VAR model in R (using the command VAR) and my model reports an R-squared of about 0.8 for the variable I'm most interested in. I'm trying to replicate that result by calculating the R-squared by hand. I have extracted the fitted values (using the command fitted(model_name)) and then I have used the following equation:

$$R^2 = 1- { \sum_{t} (y_t-\hat y_t)^2  \over \sum_{t}(y_t - \overline y)^2},$$

with $y_t$ = actual value, $ \hat y_t$ = predicted (fitted) value and $ \overline y$ = the average of the actual value.

I am taking into account the fact that my model uses two lags, so I have two fitted values less than the total amount of points used to train. I'm making sure to pair the actual and predicted values correctly.

I have tried using this equation before in regular linear regression and I am able to replicate the value I get from R, however I cannot do it with this VAR model. Is it because when the R-squared is calculated for time series, something different is done? I have tried googling this and cannot find any reference to a different equation for the case of time series.

Any comments or suggestions as to what could be wrong will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: maybe the mean is also only calculated from the "clipped" time series after discarding initial observations due to the lags?

Comment: That is a great observation. I tried that as well and it did not work

Comment: maybe you can post some code of what you did - please see my answer below, which suggests that it does work

Answer (score 1):

In principle, the procedure for computing $R^2$ should indeed be as you describe also for VAR models, as these are also simply fitted by OLS.

The discrepancy indeed seems to be in how `VAR` computes the numerator in the formula for $R^2$.

Consider the code below:

```
library(vars)

# generate some data
n <- 10
y1 <- rnorm(n)
y2 <- rnorm(n)
y <- cbind(y1,y2)

# R^2 from vars package
var.model <- VAR(y, p = 1)
R2.vars.1 <- summary(var.model$varresult$y1)$r.squared

# handmade
u1 <- resid(var.model)[,1]
# gives different results when computing numerator from full series:
#R2.1 <- 1-sum(u1^2)/sum((y1-mean(y1))^2) 

# numerator of R^2 when only using the portion that can actually serve as a dependent variable
R2.1 <- 1-sum(u1^2)/sum((y1[2:n]-mean(y1[2:n]))^2) 

all.equal(R2.1,R2.vars.1) # TRUE (identical and == say FALSE because of small numerical differences)
```

Comment: `vars::VAR` just constructs the matrix of lagged values and passes it off to `stats::lm` to do OLS, which is where the $R^2$ value comes from. `lm` never even sees the first $p$ points of the dependent variable and does not know anything about the lag relationship with the regressors, so obviously can't use these to compute the mean.